# Hice una paginación en React pero no funciona

Tags: reactjs, hook

Hice una paginación en React pero hay algo que no veo porque el botón que cambia la paginación no funciona.
Detallo el código a continuación::

Primero un Hook personalizado "usePagination". Otro Hook personalizado "useFetch" me da una lista de productos de API. En este momento, si cambio el número de estado de curretPage en dos, funciona y la lista en los componentes de ProductGrid se actualiza y me muestra los próximos 16 productos. Muestro los componentes Pagination y ProductGrid debajo del siguiente código:

```
export const usePagination = () => {

    const { data } = useFetch();

    const productsByPage = 16;
    
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);

    function refreshPage( number ) {
        const indexLastProduct = (number) * productsByPage;
        const indexFirstProduct = indexLastProduct - productsByPage;
        const list = data.slice(indexFirstProduct, indexLastProduct);
        return list;
    }

    let productList = refreshPage( currentPage );

    function changePage(number) {
        setCurrentPage(number);
    }

    return {
        productsByPage,
        productList,
        currentPage,
        changePage
    };
}
```

Los componentes de "paginación" de I llamo a la función usePagination devuelta productsByPage, productList, currentPage y "changePage". En ambos botones CustomFAB, implemento la función "changePage" que me da usePagination, y configuro en los eventos onClick el número de página para cambiar según el botón presionado:

```
export const Pagination = ( { isVisible } ) => {

    const { 
        productsByPage,
        currentPage,
        changePage } = usePagination();

    const [ filterVisivility ] = useState( isVisible );
   
    const { data } = useFetch();

    return (
        <div className="pagination-bar">
            <div 
                className="
                    store__pagination-container 
                    align-horizontal 
                    d-flex 
                    align-items-center">
                <p className="store__counter-pager">
                    { productsByPage } of { data.length } 
                    <span>products</span>
                </p>
    
                { filterVisivility && <FilterBar /> }

                <ul className="pagination-nav align-horizontal right-align">
                    <li>
                        {
                            !currentPage === 1 &&
                            <CustomFAB 
                                iconName={ 'chevron_left' } 
                                onClickFab={ ()=> { changePage( 1 ) } }
                            />
                        }
                        
                    </li> 
                    <li>
                        <CustomFAB 
                            iconName={ 'chevron_right' } 
                            onClickFab={ ()=> { changePage( 2 ) } }
                        />
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <hr />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Finalmente, en el componente ProductGrid, obtengo la lista de productos paginada del gancho usePagination para mostrar, pero algo no funciona en la comunicación entre el componente Pagination y el gancho personalizado usePagination:

```
export const ProductGrid = () => {

    const { productList } = usePagination();

    const { loading } = useFetch();

    const isMobile = useMediaQuery({ query: `(min-width: 760px)` });
    
    return (    
        <>
            { loading && <SkeletonGrid /> }
            {
                !isMobile 
                ? <OwlCarousel 
                    className='owl-theme' 
                    dots={ false }
                    items={ 1 }
                    margin={ 25 } 
                    nav>
                    {   
                        productList.map( prod => (
                            
                            <ProductItem
                                key={ prod.id }
                                { ...prod }
                            />
                        ))
                    }
                </OwlCarousel> 
                :
                <div className="row">
                    {   
                        productList.map( (prod, key) => (
                            <ProductItem
                                key={ key }
                                { ...prod }
                            />
                        ))
                    }
                </div>
            }
        </>
    )
}
```

Alguna ayuda?. Muchas gracias!

Comment: This is *StackOverflow en Español*, please edit your question and translate it to Spanish. Otherwise it will get closed.

Comment: Hecho. Gracias por la aclaración, no me di cuenta que estaba en la web en español.

Comment: Parece que el evento onClick actualiza el  productList solo de Pagination y no de ProductGrid. Podrías crear un state con el número de pagina en el parent de ambos y pasarlo a ProductGrid cuando hagas click al botón de manera que ProductGrid pueda llamar a changePage y actualizar a productList.